# How can USDZ model be imported into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

I'm trying to import USDZs for ARKit prototype. I followed the steps in this [post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/28/pixars-universal-scene-description-for-unity-out-in-preview/), but USDZ import is not supported with this process. I'm aware that **`pixyz`** can achieve this, but I'm wondering:

Is there a free method to convert a USDZ to a Unity-eligible format?

Answer (score 4):

You can't import USDZ but you can import USD.
If you have an USDZ, fire up Xcode and export it to USD.
Beside USD, Xcode can export USDZ to several other formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip the USDZ file using something like 7-zip and then import the resulting USD file with the package.

Comment: seems to only result in a USDC file, plus a few pngs.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, only [USD Unity SDK](https://forum.unity.com/threads/usd-for-unity-updates.646645/) was released as a ***Preview Package*** in 2019 for free. That's all.